# Is there any way to pass a DBCommand.Connection to SQLConnection?

Tags: .net, sqlconnection

I'm working with an object that has a connection to the Database in the form of DBCommand.Connection, and another object that takes a connection to the database in the form of SQLConnection.

Persist security is Off so I can't create a new SQLConnection since the password is stripped, any ideas of how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you're asking how to cast the [`DbCommand.Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.connection.aspx) property (which is of type `DbConnection`) to a `SqlConnection`.

Since [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) inherits of `DbConnection` you can simply cast it accordingly:

```
SqlConnection con = (SqlConnection) dbCommand.Connection;
```

Of course this assumes that the `DbConnection` is actually a `SqlConnection`.

Comment: Thanks Tim!  I thought the DBCommand was an older implementation of a .Net connection, didn't realize they were related.  Works great.